# Is there a way to filter an HP switch's log output to only show events for the specified string?

Tags: switch, hp, hp-procurve, logging

When troubleshooting a host connectivity issue, I log into an HP 5412, for example and look for possible issues on the one port by pulling up the logs.  Is there a way to filter/sort the output so that you only see the events for the desired string ("F18" for example)?  The way I have worked around this so far is to copy the logs onto a document and then do a find operation to clean up the output and isolate only what I need for my troubleshooting steps/ticket.  This can take a bit of time; is there another command or option to append to the log command which would allow to filter results (much like piping the output to grep for a string in bash).

Thanks!

Comment: You should really have a log server to which your network devices send their log messages. Log servers usually have more powerful tools for doing such things.

Comment: Thank you.  This may be something I can suggest to the Network Engineering team in my enterprise (I work in the support center for a fairly large corporation).  Excluding that possible resolution; do you know of a way to format the log commands output to sort it?

Comment: I will let the experts on HP switches answer. Some groups in our company have tried them a few times, but always ended up dumping them after a few years, so I do not have any real direct experience with them.

Comment: Procurve or Comware? As I recall, procurve is a definite no. Comware might support "grep".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most outputs, you can use the common `|i` scheme, e.g. `log | i F18`. (`i` for `include`, there's also `exclude` and `begin`.)

Comment: These are Procurve.  Thanks for the answer, tested and it worked!